# Qt MDI Area subwindow construction after show->() fails to update window size

Tags: qt, size

I have a program that constructs a subwindow in a QT MDI Area, shows it, and later updates the contents of this window.
The program is large, but I have tried (and hopefully succeded) to reproduce the problem in the little program below.
In the middle of the program, there is the line commented "if this one is commented, then OK!".
As it says, if this line is commented, then the whole subwindow contents is created before Qt goes into the event loop and everything is fine...
BUT: is the line is there, then the contents of the MDI subwindow is constructed in 2 steps (as in my original program), but only the contents built in the first step shows up!

Run the little program below...
...if you now grab the sub-window (with the mouse), to move it, then Qt suddentely realize the size is wrong and updates the subwindow contents...

I could not figure out any way to get that correctly from start.

I am running Qt 4.8.0-7 on linux (Fedora).

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QtCore>
 #include <QMainWindow>
 #include <QGroupBox>
 #include <QHBoxLayout>
 #include <QLabel>
 #include <QMdiArea>
 #include <QMdiSubWindow>

 #include <stdlib.h>

 QMdiArea* g1;
 QGroupBox* g1a;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow* main_window = new(QMainWindow);
    main_window->setObjectName("main_window");
    main_window->resize(200, 200);
    main_window->setWindowTitle("Hello");


    g1 = new QMdiArea(main_window);
    main_window->setCentralWidget(g1);

    main_window->show();

    g1a = new QGroupBox("G1A", g1);
    QVBoxLayout *g1a_l = new QVBoxLayout(g1a);
    g1a_l->addWidget(new QLabel("LABEL1"));

    QMdiSubWindow *sub_window = new QMdiSubWindow(g1);
    sub_window->setWidget(g1a);
    sub_window->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);


    app.processEvents();   //If this one is commented, then OK!

    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label2"));
    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label3"));
    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label4"));
    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label5"));
    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label6"));
    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label7"));

    sub_window->show(); //How to I get that to recaclulate the size of its contents?
    return app.exec();
 }
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Use `adjustSize` method:

```
sub_window->show(); // here or after adjustSize
sub_window->adjustSize();
```

It will adjust the size to fit sub_window contents ([from documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#adjustSize)).

Comment: it works, but it assumes I can do it at the end. It my program, the subwindow is created, attached to the MDI area, and THEN filled up in many possible different ways (the "fillers" are actually different derived class of the subwindow creator which is their common base class. The subwindow is created in the baseclass constructor).
Any way to achieve the same at subwindow creation time? (ie,to tell the subwindow to react on its contents change).
As a side note, this only fails for mdi area. If I create Dialogs instead (QDialog), then the dialog  is resized when its contents gets updated...

Comment: no space left... but I wanted to say it: Thanks for your help/time!